# UITextView Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitextview, constraints

What's is happening in my UITextView?
I want the UITextView near to the NavigationBar.

This is the result:

[image]

And this the relative Constraints:

[image]

If I add the constraints Top Space to the superview and set to Zero the result is Ok but in the storyboard the UITextView is like that:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you deselect the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" from the view controller if you don't enable the option "Under Top Bars". Otherwise it moves the content down.

[image]